# How do I create a grammar rule exception for one word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

For example, every time I write Kim Jong Un the grammar checker flags the “Un” as needing to be corrected to “UN.” I don’t want to shut off the grammar checker (especially the Capitalization rules) for the document and I’ve tried adding Un to the my custom spelling dictionary and an Autocorrect exceptions list without luck. I thought Autocorrect>Exceptions>Other Exceptions, looked promising, but when I type “Un” it adds “un” (all lowercase) to the list.

Answer (score 0):

For your "Un" autocorrect request, maybe you can do this settings: Go to **File** > **Options** > **Proofing**, under When correcting spelling and grammar in Word section, click **Settings**. Under **Grammar**, clear the checkbox for **Capitalization**.